# Yii criteria using

Tags: php, sql, yii, criteria

I have two tables `country` and `user`.

In model `country` I have relation:

```
'users' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'User', 'country_id')
```

I want to find all the countries which have at least one user. If there are no users from Germany, Germany will be excluded from the result.

Tried this one:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN user ON country.id = user.country_id';
$criteria->order = 'name ASC';
$countries = country::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

But in the result I had all the countries.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->with = array('users');
$criteria->addCondition('users.id IS NOT NULL');
$countries = Country::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

or

```
$countries = Country::model()->with('users')->findAll('users.id IS NOT NULL');
```

Note that I assumed that the primary key in the `users` table is `id`. Change it to whatever it is in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. I will try out and make feedback as soon as possible.